# Using an array for autofilter criteria

Tags: excel, autofilter, vba

I have the below code which will delete rows based on criteria in column I:

```
Sub Strip()
    Dim rng As Range

    With ActiveSheet
        .Columns("I").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="=70-79%", VisibleDropDown:=False
        Set rng = .AutoFilter.Range
    End With
    If rng.Columns("I").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Count - 1 > 0 Then
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        rng.Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Delete
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    End If
    rng.AutoFilter
End Sub
```

I have about `100` different criteria that I want to act on in this way. I'd rather not have to repeat this code `100` times, and so can anyone tell me how to code this in the form of an array? I've tried various methods but can't seem to get it to work.

Comment: @Jeeped. I went through the link. I may be missing something here. :) How is this question a duplicate? That question is addressing something altogether different topic.

Comment: You have 100 different criteria. You build a dictionary of the values from a key column by looping through the rows, adding or not adding according to your 100 criterias. You then filter on the keys and delete.

Comment: I am sorry but I respectfully disagree with you. I am reopening the thread

Answer (score 6):

Use

```
.Columns("I").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=MyArray,  Operator:=xlFilterValues
```

Where `MyArray` is a string Array

**Example**

```
Dim MyArray(1 To 4) As String

MyArray(1) = "This"
MyArray(2) = "is"
MyArray(3) = "an"
MyArray(4) = "array"

'
'~~> Rest of code
'

.Columns("I").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=MyArray, Operator:=xlFilterValues

'
'~~> Rest of code
'
```

**Screenshot**

[image]

Comment: Would it also work if the array is from a `ParamArray` parameter?

Comment: Unfortunately mix of datatypes cause problems. The autofilter criteria needs to be of type String. For example if you replace `MyArray(2) = "is"` with `MyArray(2) = 1` and `As String` to `As Variant` then it will not filter out that value.

Comment: Thanks, I have something to play with for a while.

Comment: You can covert each element of the array to string using CSTR