# Wildcard autofilter criteria using an array

Tags: excel, vba

I've read various threads on this but can't seem to get my code to work with it. It seems you're unable to have more than 2 wildcard criteria in an array to use as autofilter criteria. No idea why that is, but my code is currently this:

```
Sub Strip_Description()
Dim rng As Range
Dim MyArray(1 To 258) As String

MyArray(1) = "*Ecoss*"
.
.
MyArray(258) = "*some wildcard value*"

    With ActiveSheet
    .Columns("D").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=MyArray, Operator:=xlFilterValues
    Set rng = .AutoFilter.Range
    End With
    If rng.Columns("D").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Count - 1 > 0 Then
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    rng.Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    End If
    rng.AutoFilter
    End Sub
```

I have a large number of wildcard criteria in the array values. Any ideas on how to allow those to work?

Comment: refer to the answer in this post. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44600448/using-an-array-for-autofilter-criteria/44600520?noredirect=1