# VBA code - database Autofilter with cells in orther Sheet

Tags: excel, vba

i need your help on the VBA code :
i would like to make a filter on a database according cells in another sheets
my code is working but make a filter only in one cell. How to filter if the code found all cells from the Range

Please see my code :

```
Sub test()


Sheets("Dashboard").Select
Dim arr As Variant

'arr = Sheets("Dashboard").Range("B4:B11")
With Sheets("Database")

With .Range("A1:Z" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)
            .AutoFilter 'Turn off any previous filtering
            .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Sheets("Dashboard").Range("B4:B11")
        End With
End With
End Sub
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Please provide some sample data and the expected results

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44600448/using-an-array-for-autofilter-criteria

Comment: There are many more answers in Stackoverflow. Store that range in an array and then pass that array to  `Criteria1`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Sub SubRangeBasedAutofilter()
    
    'Declarations.
    Dim RngCell As Range
    Dim RngCriteria As Range
    Dim StrCriteria() As String
    Dim DblCriteriaCount As Double
    
    'Selecting Dashboard sheet.
    Sheets("Dashboard").Select '<-IS THIS NECESSARY?
    
    'Setting RngCriteria.
    Set RngCriteria = Sheets("Dashboard").Range("B4:B11")
    
    'Redeclaring StrCriteria() with proper size.
    ReDim StrCriteria(Excel.WorksheetFunction.Max(Excel.WorksheetFunction.CountA(RngCriteria) - 1, 1))
    
    'Covering each in RngCriteria.
    For Each RngCell In RngCriteria
        'Checking if RngCell is not empty.
        If RngCell.Value <> "" Then
            'Storing the criteria.
            StrCriteria(DblCriteriaCount) = "=" & RngCell.Value
            DblCriteriaCount = DblCriteriaCount + 1
        End If
    Next
    
    'Focusing Database sheet.
    With Sheets("Database")
        'Turning off any eventual autofilter.
        .AutoFilterMode = False
            'Setting a new autofilter.
            With .Range("A1:Z" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)
                .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=StrCriteria, Operator:=xlFilterValues
            End With
    End With
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Hello, amazing it's working :) thanks a lot for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

Please, test the next way:

```
Sub filterByRange()
 Dim arr, rng As Range
 
 Set rng = Sheets("Dashboard").Range("B4:B11")
 rng.TextToColumns Destination:=rng.cells(1), FieldInfo:=Array(1, 2)
 arr = rng.Value     
 arr = Application.Transpose(Application.Index(arr, 0, 1)) '1D array

 With Sheets("Database")
   With .Range("A1:Z" & .cells(.Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).row)
            .AutoFilter
            .AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:=arr, Operator:=xlFilterValues
   End With
 End With
End Sub
```

Comment: @johns90: You received two answers. Didn't you find some time to test them? If you tested the above one, didn't it do what you need?

Comment: Hello thanks for your feedback, i tried it and it's autofil everything. I forgot to say sorry, inside the cell B4 to B11from Dashboard tab  it's numbers

Comment: @johns90: I am not sure I correctly understood what you mean... What does "autofill everything" mean? Should I suppose that the filter does not work? Anyhow, if numbers in the criteria range, it must be formatted as text. The best way should be using of TextToColumns. I will adapt the code to do it automatically. It will not bother the code even if it is already well  formatted and the code works... The criteria must be **text** in all cases. I mean, even if an array...

Comment: @johns90: Please, test the updated code and send some feedback

Answer (score 0):

Less is more.  I adapted the code provided by @FaneDuru utilising some shortcuts.  Please note that when it comes to AutoFilter, there’s (usually) no need to specify the complete range you want to filter – it filters all rows meeting the criteria so last column is irrelevant.  As long as the data is contiguous, there’s no need to specify the last row either.

Provided for interest only.

```
Sub testFilter()
Dim Arr

Arr = Sheets("Dashboard").Range("B4:B11").Value
Arr = Application.Transpose(Application.Index(Arr, 0, 1))

With Sheets("Database").Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    .AutoFilter 1, Array(Arr), 7
End With

End Sub
```